# Execute a async method in Invoke Code of Uipath

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exchangewebservices, uipath

**Objective:** Move a Mail into an Outlook subfolder that does not exist. That is why I have to create that folder and subfolder in Outlook.

**Possible solution**: I decided to try ExchangeWebservice to achieve the creation of the folder and subfolder because I could not find an official package from Uipath to do it. This code must be executed in Uipath with Invoke Code.

```
string[] args ={appId, sharedMailboxAddress, mailboxAddress, folderPath};

    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("### Start of create Folder ###");

                // Configure the MSAL client to get token  
                var pca = Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(args[0]).Build();
    
                // The permission scope required for EWS access
                var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
                
                try
                {
                    Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult authResult;
                    try
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Make the silent token request");
                        // Make the silent token request
                        var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
                        authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(ewsScopes,accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();  
                    }
                    catch(Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"{ex}");
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Make the interactive token request");
                        // Make the interactive token request
                        authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();   
                    }
                    
                    // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Configure the ExchangeService with the access token");    
                    var ewsClient = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                    ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                    ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                    
                    FolderView fv = new FolderView(100);
                    
                    // Set Root Mailbox FolderId
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"Shared Mailbox: {args[1]}"); 
                    FolderId RootMailboxFolderId = null;
                    if(args[1]!="")
                    {
                        RootMailboxFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, args[1]); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RootMailboxFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);  
                    }
                    
                    string s = args[3];
                    string[] newFolders = s.Split('\\');
                        
                    var parentFolderId = RootMailboxFolderId;
                    
                    foreach(string folder in newFolders)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"Parent folder: {parentFolderId}");
                        
                        var findChildFolder = ewsClient.FindFolders(
                            parentFolderId,
                            new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                                Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator.Or,
                                new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(FolderSchema.DisplayName, folder)),
                            fv);
                        if(findChildFolder==null)
                        {
                            //Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633637(v=exchg.80)
                            // Create a generic folder with a valid ExchangeService object
                            Folder newFolder = new Folder(ewsClient);
                            // Set the folder properties
                            newFolder.DisplayName = folder;
                            // Save the new folder in a specified parent folder.
                            newFolder.Save(parentFolderId);
                            parentFolderId = newFolder.Id;
                            System.Console.WriteLine($"Child Folder created successfully");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine($"Child Folder {folder} exists");  
                        }
                    }
                
                }   
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    //return ex.Message;
                }
                
        }   
            
Main(args);
```

**Current issues:** When I execute my code and it implements the below piece of code, the code does not continue in the invoke code and jumps directly to the next activity "Move Exchange Mail Message" in my workflow

```
authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

[image]

If I understood correctly this method run asynchronously and the keyword await suspend while the user types its credentials. I have two questions:

1. Should I keep going on this approach or is there another easy solution to solve my requirement?
2. If this is the right approach, How should I keep the execution without jumping to the next activity?.

Comment: The problem isn't executing an asynchronous action but *awaiting* until it completes. At the very end your code calls `Main(args);` instead of `await Main(args)` which means the operation is never awaited. The script will run on the calling thread until the first wall to `await` and then yield to the caller, awaiting the nested async operation to complete. The caller itself must use `await` to await the top level operation. That means that you need to use `await Main(args)` *and* that UiPath itself should await

Comment: BTW there's no need for a `Main` function with an `args` argument in this case. You aren't running a standalone program. The `appId, sharedMailboxAddress, mailboxAddress, folderPath` variables are already available to the entire script. It would help you though if you broke the big `Main` function into smaller properly named functions that do specific things and only use the arguments they need

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos tks for your help. I added the keyword await but I got the compiler error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return Type to 'Task'. It seems that Invoke Code from Uipath is already a Method. Do you know how to solve it?.

Comment: Invoke code cannot work with async. This is not possible. Sorry,